# Can't send JSON data via res.json

Tags: json, reactjs, express, fetch

when I send a fetch request for JSON data, it returns the response object, but not the data itself.

Can't figure out why

I've tried added headers, stringifying the data

My Express server

```
const productData = require('./storeProducts.json');

app.use(cors());


app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(JSON.stringify(productData));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Now listening on ${PORT}`));
```

my fetch request

```
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/products');
    console.log(data)
  };
```

when I console.log the data i am receiving, instead of the JSON object, im getting

Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3001/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3001/products"
**proto**: Response

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
const fetchProducts = async () => {
let data = [];
await fetch('http://localhost:3001/products')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => {data = response;})
console.log(data)
};
```

When you use fetch, it returns an object and res.json() method extracts the JSON data from that object and returns a promise, that promise can be used to perform our operations on the result. e.g mapping data on a table, making graphs, chart, authentication etc.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot about that

Comment: you can mark the answer as solution, you know. It'll be good for my reputation.